# Count how many times a string appears in a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a big database that stores data from a form. The only answers of the form are yes or no, so in the database there are the 62 names of the questions with stored the answers (yes or no) and a uid. I need to count how many times yes and no appears and store it in a variable. How can I do this? 
An example of the stored data is like this: tl1a->yes , tl2a->no , ..., uid->1234

Comment: Is there a separate column for each answer? Or is that example a string in one column?

Comment: *"I need to count how many times"* - The operative word here is "count", which is both a PHP and MySQL function.

Answer (score 1):

Just for example ...

```
SELECT 
    *,    
    ROUND (   
        (
            LENGTH(`yourfield`)
            - LENGTH( REPLACE ( `yourfield`, "yes", "") ) 
        ) / LENGTH("yes")        
    ) AS count    
FROM `yourtable`
```

in same manner for "no"

hope it will work...